Public exchanges US treasuries
I know the major part of US treasuries is traded OTC through RFQs. I was wondering though if there are public exchanges like for US equities where retail investors can send market and limit orders to buy US treasuries?  If such exchanges exist, I'd like to know which ones they are and how many there are.
I believe it exists because for example when I buy a US treasuries on Interactive Broker I am basically sending a market order to buy that US Treasury. So I was wondering if these public exchanges exists and which are they as I wasn't able to find anything on that on the internet.

(1) As a customer of IBKR you are entitled to an explanation of where your trades are executed, so just ask. (2) It is possible that IBKR uses Tradeweb Bonddesk to trade US treasuries electronically (but that's a guess)  https://tradeweb.com/our-markets/institutional/rates/government-bonds
